# ATTLIST declaration in html5

Tags: html, doctype, dtd

Im having an issue with custom attrubutes in html5 document.
My source code starts with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
[
 <!ATTLIST img pid ID #IMPLIED>
]>
```

When im trying to validate my html file in W3C validator it doesnt determine my documents doctype and tells that my doctype declaration is wrong.
So my question is, how can I declare custom attributes in HTML5? Is it even possible at the moment in HTML5? I couldnt find any relevant information on the internet.

Comment: HTML 5 is not an SGML application and does not have a DTD. The Doctype exists purely for backwards compatibility with browsers that use it to trigger Standards mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DOCTYPE` you are trying is invalid, it should be `<!DOCTYPE html>` which is a valid `doctype` for HTML5 and as far as the custom attributes go, you need to use `data-` prefix which will be considered as valid custom attribute.

```
<p data-custom-attribute="Value"></p>
```

> <sup>[1]</sup> A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name
>   starts with the string `data-`, has at least one character after the
>   hyphen, is `XML`-compatible, and contains no uppercase `ASCII` letters.

<sup>1. [Reference](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes)</sup>